# correct URL on home page redirect to wrong page

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink

The homepage of my site is running fine. But, when I click on a spesific link on the homepage, it  redirects me to a different link. The URL's seem to be working correctly, since the URL's do change when a link is clicked, but not the page. Everything worked fine up until Friday, but it just stopped working automatically. What could cause the problem?

Comment: No idea what's happening, but you could try going to permalinks and re-saving them. That's known to fix a few bugs with urls.

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Answer (score 0):

You could use get_bloginfo('home') to get the link of yout home page, try to put this in the a that you wanna link to your home page.